# CheckBox in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a Database block contains 3 columns. in that all are character columns.
I have created a multi record block in a form which contains 2 text item and one check box.

The values in the table are like below

col1        col2       col3

value1  value2  N

Value3  value4  N

Value5  value6  Y

In the form, I want to find only the records with Value 'N' in the col3.

I want to find the values using Enter - Query, Execute Query method, But here in my form, col3 is the checkbox. if ticked -Y, not ticked value will be 'N'.

I know, we cannot search 'N' values using Enter - Query, Execute Query method.

Is there Any other way we can search?

Comment: You can override the `pre-query` trigger for the block and set the `where clause` there based on the value of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in enter-query standard functionality is that the checkbox contains an empty value (null) and is not unchecked. To search for an unchecked value just go in enter-query mode and click the checkbox to have the "Y" value in your case and click it again to have the "N" value. From now on you can check and uncheck the value.
If you have made a mistake and want it to be empty again use the clear item key to set it back to null.

Comment: If you set a initial value for the check box then it will nto be NULL when you go into enter-query mode.

Comment: No that is not right, initial value is a default, it is only for a new record. Not for querying

Comment: Please see my post, with that settings the query did work without the need for first clicking the check box. It is though possible that it is the combination of Initial Value and Check Box Mapping of Other Values set to 'Not Allowed'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow querying the block based on the checkbox, you need to have the checkbox values stored somewhere, probably in a Y/N column on the table that the block is based on.

Before the block is queried, you'd just need to ensure the checkbox values are posted to the database.

If you can't save them to the table itself, an alternative would be to save them somewhere else, but it has to be something accessible to the query itself - e.g. a global temporary table.

Comment: i am storing the check box values. in the form, i want to query only the records having the value 'N' in col3. How we can do this?

Comment: I've told you. You need to store the checkbox values somewhere that the database can access them. When you run a query *on the server*, it cannot read the values from the checkboxes that are implemented *on the client*.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the check box to enter the needed search criteria form col3? I can't see why that should not be possible and I even tested it quickly. Please try the following

Set properties of your checkbox for col3 as follows

- Value when Checked = Y
- Value when Unchecked = N
- Check Box Mapping of Other Values = Not Allowed
- Initial Value = N or Y whatever suites your business need
- Database Item = Yes
- Column Name = col3

If using this kind of settings you can in Enter Query mode select if you want the query for col3  = N by making sure that the check box is unchecked when executing the query.